# How to select function definitions as a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle12c, function-definition

I would like to select the PL/SQL definition of all functions in a schema as a query. The reason being I want to query all my functions for specific text.

I can do this for views like so:

```
select * from all_views
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this with functions.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all functions, you can query [the `ALL_OBJECTS` dictionary view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_OBJECTS.html#GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976) :

```
SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```

This will give you all the functions available to the current user (`DBA_OBJECTS` lists all objects in the database).

Then, you can retrieve the text source of the function from view [`ALL_SOURCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_SOURCE.html#GUID-FD480C9E-F8DB-40DF-A04D-65765C45EA2F) :

```
SELECT o.object_name, s.line, s.text 
FROM all_objects o
INNER JOIN all_source s 
    ON s.name = o.object_name AND s.type = o.object_type AND s.owner = o.owner
WHERE o.object_type = 'FUNCTION';
```